# How many subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}_4 \times \Bbb{Z}_6$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

I have been trying to calculate the number of subgroups of the direct cross product $\Bbb{Z}_4 \times \Bbb{Z}_6.$ Using Goursat's Theorem, I can calculate 16. Here's the info:

Goursat's Theorem: Let $G_1 \times G_2$ be a group and let $A/B$ be a subquotient of $G_1$ and $C/D$ be a subquotient of $G_2.$ Also, $\varphi: A/B \to C/D$ is an isomorphism. Then there exists a bijection from the set of all subgroups of $G_1 \times G_2$ and the set of all triples $(A/B, C/D, \varphi)$.

So I counted all the subquotients of $\Bbb{Z}_4$ (there are 6) and all the subquotients of $\Bbb{Z}_6$ (there are 9). There are only 2 isomorphisms. I label them $\varphi_1: \{ 0 \} \to \{ 0 \}$ and $\varphi_2: \Bbb{Z}_2 \to \Bbb{Z}_2$ (because every subquotient is isomorphic to either $\{0\}$ or $\Bbb{Z}_2$). Both of these isomorphisms has only one possible automorphism. So we need only calculate the different combinations of mappings from $A/B$ to $C/D.$

For $\varphi_1,$ there are $3 \times 4 = 12$ possible mappings. For $\varphi_2,$ there are $2 \times 2 = 4$ possible mappings. Thus, there should be a total of 12+4=16 isomorphisms. By Goursat's Theorem, there must be 16 subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}_4 \times \Bbb{Z}_6$.

Only problem is, when I look at every subgroup lattice for $\Bbb{Z}_4 \times \Bbb{Z}_6$, there are only 15 subgroups!

Using my method above (Goursat's Theorem), what am I doing wrong? Or, am I looking at the wrong subgroup lattice (less likely)?

P.S. Let me know if you need more info about my counting methods.

Comment: How do you get 6 quotient groups of $\Bbb Z_4$?  Any quotient group of $\Bbb Z_4$ must have the form $\Bbb Z_4/N$ where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $\Bbb Z_4$.  But $\Bbb Z_4$ has only 3 subgroups, all of which are normal, so it should have 3 quotient groups also.

Comment: @MJD Goursat's theorem relies on what should be called *sections* or *subquotients*, here where $A/B$ and $A'/B'$ can be distinct even if they are isomorphic.

Comment: @MJD The 6 quotient groups of $\Bbb{Z}_4$ are: $\Bbb{Z}_4 / \Bbb{Z}_4,$ $\Bbb{Z}_4 / \langle 2 \rangle,$ $\Bbb{Z}_4 / \{ 0 \},$ $\langle 2 \rangle / \langle 2 \rangle,$ $\langle 2 \rangle / \{0\}$ and $\{0\} / \{0\}.$

Comment: There's no need to list the subquotients. The reason for MJD's comment is that you used the term "quotient" instead of the more general concept of "subquotient" (which is what you are actually talking about).

Comment: @anon I see now. Yes, thank you. I hadn't heard the term subquotient before.

Comment: Yes, my comment was based on a misunderstanding,  because I know nothing at all about Goursat's lemma. Please pardon my interruption.

Comment: Could you point us to one of these subgroup lattices you mention looking at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a picture of the lattice of subgroups. I thought you might find it interesting.

[image: The lattice of subgroups]

Comment: Wow! Thank you. It looks perfect and not anything like the other subgroup lattices I saw! This is what I have found everywhere else: [link](https://math.la.asu.edu/~kawski/classes/mat444/handouts/Z4xZ6.gif). I'm assuming there is an extra subgroup that is not cyclic and that is why it wouldn't have shown up in the others...Also, how did you draw this? A LaTeX package? (I've been using xy to draw lattices.)

Comment: I used the computer algebra package GAP. [Here's](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html) a link to the part of the GAP manual about groups, if you're interested. It can make lattices for all of the small groups.

Answer (score 4):

Your computation with Goursat's lemma appears to be correct.

Here is a complete list of all the subgroups of $C_4\times C_2\times C_3$:

- Order $24$

  - $C_4\times C_2\times C_3$

    - $\langle (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\rangle$
- Order $12$

  - $C_2\times C_2\times C_3$

    - $\langle (2,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\rangle$
  - $C_4\times C_3$

    - $\langle (1,0,0),(0,0,1)\rangle$
    - $\langle (1,1,0),(0,0,1)\rangle$
- Order $8$

  - $C_4\times C_2$

    - $\langle(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\rangle$
- Order $6$

  - $C_2\times C_3$

    - $\langle(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\rangle$
    - $\langle(2,1,0),(0,0,1)\rangle$
    - $\langle(2,0,0),(0,0,1)\rangle$
- Order $4$

  - $C_2\times C_2$

    - $\langle(0,1,0),(2,0,0)\rangle$
  - $C_4$

    - $\langle (1,0,0)\rangle$
    - $\langle (1,1,0)\rangle$
- Order $3$

  - $C_3$

    - $\langle(0,0,1)\rangle$
- Order $2$

  - $C_2$

    - $\langle(0,1,0)\rangle$
    - $\langle(2,1,0)\rangle$
    - $\langle(2,0,0)\rangle$
- Order $1$

  - Trivial group

That's a total of $16$ distinct subgroups of $C_4\times C_2\times C_3$.